# AVSynchronizedLayer does not play animations on macOS

Tags: macos, avfoundation, core-graphics, core-animation

I can't make animations to work with `AVSynchronizedLayer` on **macOS**. When the player is playing, nothing is animated in the `AVSynchronizedLayer`.

Interestingly, when I use almost identical code on iOS, it works fine :<

```swift
// Load audio file and setup AVPlayer
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "debugAudio", withExtension: "m4a")!
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)

// AVSync layer
let syncLayer = AVSynchronizedLayer(playerItem: avPlayer.currentItem!)
view.layer!.addSublayer(syncLayer)
syncLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 60, width: 200, height: 200)

// Progress layer which we'll animate
let progressLayer = CALayer()
progressLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.purple.cgColor
progressLayer.borderColor = NSColor.orange.cgColor
syncLayer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
progressLayer.frame = syncLayer.bounds

// Animation
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
anim.fromValue = 3.0
anim.toValue = 20.0
anim.duration = 5.0
anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
anim.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
progressLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)

// Play
self.avPlayer.play()
```

Comment: I did some more testing and I found out that the animations work correctly only if two other conditions are met. 1) I'm playing a video, not just audio. 2) The player is connected to some AVPlayerLayer. | This is weird, don't you think? Shouldn't this all work for audio-only items too?

Comment: a very small `AVPlayerLayer` with a very small video?